# Rails ActiveRecord save error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, save, runtime-error

I am getting an error when trying to save my model object in rails. Let me say that I did not use database migrations and am using a pre-existing database with rails. 
Here is my model class:

```
require 'bcrypt'
require 'securerandom'
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  self.table_name = 'profiles'
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  attr_accessor :id, :username, :password_hash, :salt, :first_name, :last_name, :location, :status, :game_status

  def initialize(attributes = {}, options = {})
    @username = attributes[:username]
    @salt = SecureRandom.hex
    @password_hash = Password.create(attributes[:password] + @salt).to_s
    @first_name = attributes[first_name]
    @last_name = attributes[last_name]
    @location = attributes[location]
    @status = "Hi"
    @game_status = "Playing some game..."
  end

  def hash_rep
    hash = {}
    hash['id'] = @id
    hash['username'] = @username
    hash['password_hash'] = @password_hash
    hash['salt'] = @salt
    hash['location'] = @location
    hash['status'] = @status
    hash['game_status'] = @game_status
    return hash
  end

end
```

Here is my database schema:

```
id             int Unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
username       varchar(16)  NOT NULL
password_hash  tinytext     NOT NULL
salt           varchar(64)  NOT NULL
first_name     varchar(16)  NOT NULL
last_name      varchar(16)  NOT NULL
location       tinytext     NOT NULL
status         tinytext     NULL
game_status    tinytext     NULL
```

Here is my code for my controller:

```
  def register
    profile = Profile.new(:id => params[:id],
                          :username => params[:username],
                          :password => params[:password],
                          :first_name => params[:first_name],
                          :last_name => params[:last_name],
                          :location => params[:location])
    profile.save
    render_profile(profile)
  end
```

The error occurs on the 'profile.save' method. Here is the relevant stacktrace:

```
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:375:in `clear_transaction_record_state'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:306:in `ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:306:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
app/controllers/profile_controller.rb:52:in `register'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
```

The error says: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: There is no local variable named `params` in `register`. That said, local variable `params` is being initialized to `nil` on first appearance; `params[:id]` is hereby equivalent to `nil[:id]` causing the error you’ve got.

Comment: Step through this in the console: set params by copying from your log and step through the code line by line.  You should be able to see what's not right.

Comment: ouch, you're doing many wrong stuff: no need for attr_accessors when its about table columns, dont ever redefine initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'bcrypt'
require 'securerandom'
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  self.table_name = 'profiles'
  self.primary_key = 'id'

  def hash_rep
    hash = {}
    hash['id'] = id
    hash['username'] = username
    hash['password_hash'] = password_hash
    hash['salt'] = salt
    hash['location'] = location
    hash['status'] = status
    hash['game_status'] = game_status
    hash
  end

  def self.build(args)
    new_profile = Profile.new
    new_profile.username = args[:username]
    salt = SecureRandom.hex
    new_profile.password_hash = Password.create(args[:password] + salt).to_s
    new_profile.first_name = args[:first_name]
    new_profile.last_name = args[:last_name]
    new_profile.location = args[:location]
    new_profile.status = "Hi"
    new_profile.game_status = "Playing some game..."
    new_profile
  end
end
```

Now you could use it like:

```
Profile.build({ username: 'foo' })
```

Btw, your hash_rep method is not that useful, try:

```
profile = Profile.build({ username: 'foo' })
profile.attributes
```

Sidenotes:

- since you follow conventions, you dont need to add those lines, you can just remove them: `self.table_name = 'profiles'`, `self.primary_key = 'id'`
- beware of hashes, seems you dont care about string or symbol keys, but they are not the same
- there are more elegant way to write your methods, but I've kept it simple because its not necessary to elaborate at this stage

Answer (score 0):

In your new method, you should change these to be symbols, from:

```
@first_name = attributes[first_name]
@last_name = attributes[last_name]
@location = attributes[location]
```

To:

```
@first_name = attributes[:first_name]
@last_name = attributes[:last_name]
@location = attributes[:location]
```

Also, you don't need to pass in an options hash? As you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to set default properties in rails is via callbacks:

```
require 'bcrypt'
require 'securerandom'
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  attr_accessor :password # is a virtual attribute

  after_initialize do
    if new_record?
      # values will be available for new record forms.
      self.status = status || "Hi"
      self.game_status = game_status || "Playing some game..."
    end
  end

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.salt = SecureRandom.hex
    self.password_hash = Password.create(password + salt).to_s
  end

    # Yuck. use http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serialization/serializable_hash
  def hash_rep
    serializable_hash( only: [:id, :username, :password_hash, :salt, :location, :status, :game_status] )
  end

end
```

You don't need to create accessors for ActiveRecord columns. You don't need to specify the `table` and `primary_key`. Rails figures that out for you. Also you REALLY don't want to redefine `initialize` since active record has a bunch going on there.

Your controller is also missing the mark. Rails usually nests parameters under the resource name. If you are using Rails 4 - you would [whitelist](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and assign the parameters by:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController 

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def register
    @profile = Profile.new(create_params)
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to @profile 
    else 
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private
  def create_params
    params.require(:profile).allow(:username, :password, : first_name :last_name :location)
  end
end
```

Comment: I dont agree, callbacks are a plague. If you need default values when you build something, you're just using a builder. Its part of the well known and used design patterns

Comment: Having tons of boilerplate assignment code dangling all over sounds like a really good idea - not.

Comment: true, there are better ways but you're answering a beginner. So no need to confuse him right now. BTW, he coulnt use your code without getting an exception: `password is not an attribute`

Comment: Edited to add accessor for password. But really he should be using [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) and not trying to do password digests from scratch. Its just too easy to mess up.

Comment: :) abstraction is possible once you feel comfortable with the tools, step by step....

Comment: BTW, replace your `before_save` with a `before_create` or it would fail... callbacks...

Comment: True but in that case it should be `before_validation` since validation occurs before `before_create `. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: `before_validation` happens before each save (and before each `.valid?` call)

Comment: you should really change, it will make things wrong on update :)